# How to remove battery optimisation in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to remove battery optimization from the app programmatically to run service longer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. All you can do is to check SDK version and for if v26+ then warn your user about potential issues this feature may cause and ask him/her to disable optimization for your application and then open settings pane using [ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. Any idea to detect battery optimization enable or disable so I can launch intent for settings. I saw this in StepSetGo app

Comment: @AzayGupta if Sdk_version >=26, then there is battery optimization by default. Xiaomi and huawei have custom settings for battery optimisation, which intent actions you can find in net

Comment: @liaKuzmin I found intent but unable to detect whether the optimization setting is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an other **Intent** `Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`, Google Play Store will ask you why you want to remove the optimizations when uploading.

```
val intentSettings = Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)
with(intentSettings) {
    data = Uri.fromParts("package", context.packageName, null)
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
}
context.startActivity(intentSettings)
```

Also you have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />` to your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library that helps navigate your user to settings screen that whitelists your app for these EOMs: https://github.com/WaseemSabir/BatteryPermissionHelper

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34461702)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable battery optimization. Use WorkManager,Firebase and Foreground Service. Beware of using long operations in Service.

Comment: I'm using Foreground Service. but in a few devices like Xiaomi, battery optimization by default activated. The closing app from recent always killed all services in those devices. even I'm using  START_STICKY services.

Comment: All that you can do is manually lock application in task manager or settings. There is no way to do it programmatically.

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean by locking the app in task manager or settings?

Comment: you can also ask for auto start permission in chinese device in order to run background services