# Coroutine launched from foreground service getting paused

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

I am updating a notification every second.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class StopwatchService : Service() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var stopwatch: Stopwatch

    // scope
    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job) // which dispatcher to use?

    // notifications
    private val notificationManager by lazy { getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager }

    private val notificationBuilder by lazy {
        createNotificationBuilder(title = stopwatch.laps.size.let { if (it > 0) "Lap ${it + 1}" else "" })
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        intent?.action.let {
            when (it) {              
                Actions.START_SERVICE.name -> {
                    startForeground(
                        ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build()
                    )

                    scope.launch {
                        Log.d("stopwatch-service", "state LAUNCH")

                        stopwatch.eventFlow.collectLatest {
                            Log.d("stopwatch-service", "state ${it.toString()}")

                            when (it) {
                                Stopwatch.Event.START -> {
                                    notificationBuilder.clearActions()
                                    ...
                                }

                                Stopwatch.Event.STOP -> {
                                    notificationBuilder.clearActions()
                                    ...
                                }

                                Stopwatch.Event.RESET -> {
                                    stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
                                    stopSelf()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    scope.launch {
                        Log.d("stopwatch-service", "update LAUNCH")

                        stopwatch.elapsedTimeFlow(
                            refreshRate = 100,
                            precision = 1000,
                            format = ::formatNotification,
                            uiScope = scope,
                            updateUI = false
                        ).collectLatest {
                            Log.d("stopwatch-service", "update $it")
                            notificationManager.notify(
                                ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                notificationBuilder.apply { setContentText(it) }.build()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        Log.d("stopwatch-service", "onStartCommand ${intent.toString()}")
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("stopwatch-service", "onDestroy")
        job.cancel()
    }
```

```
state LAUNCH
onStartCommand Intent { act=START_SERVICE cmp=com.uzential.stopwatch/.services.StopwatchService }
update LAUNCH
state START
update 00:01
update 00:02
update 00:03
...
update 00:28
update 00:29
update 00:30
update 00:31
update 01:48
update 01:49
update 01:50
update 01:51
...
update 02:06
update 02:07
update 02:08
update 02:09
update 04:08
update 04:09
update 04:10
update 04:11
```

The coroutine is paused (until I press an action button) for a minute even if the notification is visible.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755446/coroutine-flow-is-paused-when-the-app-is-in-the-background#comment123301893_69755446) comment, I enabled "Allow background activity" in App Info -> Battery usage, which seems to have fixed the issue. I am surprised this has to be done for a foreground service. Is updating a notification expensive? (`notificationManager.notify` simply changes the content text field, but no UI calculations are performed until the notification is visible)

I am using `Dispatchers.Default` to avoid using the main thread.

```
fun Stopwatch.elapsedTimeFlow(
    uiScope: CoroutineScope,
    format: (millis: Long) -> String,
    refreshRate: Long = 100,
    precision: Long = 1000,
    updateUI : Boolean = true,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
): Flow<String> {
    // flow
    val elapsedTimeFlow = MutableStateFlow(elapsedTime)
    suspend fun refreshLoop() {
        while (true) {
            elapsedTimeFlow.value = elapsedTime
            delay(refreshRate)
        }
    }
    // listen to changes to isRunning
    uiScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        val job = AtomicReference<Job?>(null)
        eventFlow.collectLatest {
            when (it) {
                // launch refresh loop
                Stopwatch.Event.START -> {
                    launch {
                        refreshLoop()
                    }.also(job::set)
                }
                // cancel refresh loop
                Stopwatch.Event.STOP, Stopwatch.Event.RESET -> {
                    job.get()?.cancel()
                    // update UI one last time
                    if(updateUI) elapsedTimeFlow.emit(elapsedTime)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // UI flow
    return elapsedTimeFlow
        .map { it / precision }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map { format(elapsedTime) }
        .flowOn(dispatcher)
}
```

Battery optimization [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753476/20898396) be disabled programmatically. Is there something else that can be done, like allowing pausing the coroutine only if the notification is not visible?

Edit: The same thing happens with a simple log.

```
Actions.START_SERVICE.name -> {
                    startForeground(
                        ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build()
                    )

                    scope.launch {
                        while(true){
                            Log.d("stopwatch-service", "LOG ${stopwatch.elapsedTime}")
                            delay(1000)
                        }
```

```
LOG 28559
LOG 29565
LOG 161978 (after clicking on the notification)
```

Edit 2: Timers are also stopped.

```
                    val timerTask = object : TimerTask() {
                        override fun run() {
                            Log.d("stopwatch-service", "LOG ${stopwatch.elapsedTime}")
                        }
                    }
                    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000)
```

```
LOG 28816
LOG 29817
LOG 46124 (clicked on notification)
```

Comment: I'm working on a similar project and I've made a programatic journey going from WorkManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager), to ForegroundService with a dispatcher (as you have here), to now probably going back to WorkManager, due to the reasons you've listed here.

WorkManager has a lot of shortcomings when it comes to communicating between jobs <-> rest of the app (no DB access, for instance). But at least it runs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The foreground service itself seem so keep running regardless, so I did a solution like this:

```
    override fun onCreate() {
    ...
    Thread {
        run {
            // Hack to attempt to restart cancelled routines due to Android's unconfigurable battery management
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(10000)
                routineMap.forEach { (_, job) ->
                    if(job.isCancelled) {
                        job.start()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    ...
    }
```

Where the the foregound service starts a thread which simply restarts the jobs that gets cancelled. Seems to work quite well. The only caveat is that you need to keep track of the Jobs that you wish to keep running.

Comment: Wouldn't `Thread.sleep` also be "paused" like `delay` and not wake up right away? (I don't think the job is cancelled, just that `delay(1000)`` takes a lot longer to return after 30 seconds)